# Что содержится внутри переменной которой присвоен объект

Tags: php, ооп

Ну например есть класс:

```
class A
{
    public $value = 100;
}
```

И есть переменная с экземпляром объекта:

```
$obj = new A;
```

Насколько я слышал что в переменной хранится не совсем объект а какой-то ID?
К примеру следующий код:

```
$cop = $obj;
$ref = &$obj;
$obj->value = 1;
echo $obj->value," ",$cop->value," ",$ref->value,"\n"; /// 1 1 1
$obj = NULL;
var_dump($obj,$cop,$ref); /// NULL object(A)#1 NULL
```

Объясните так все же что хранится в переменной которой присваевается "объект".

Answer (score 3):

Для ответа на этот вопрос надо лезть в дебри управления памятью и представления переменных. Счастья добавляет, что как раз это представление довольно сильно изменилось в PHP7 и комплексный ответ требует описать обе модели. Описание этой кухни в минимальном виде потребовало уже статей в двух частях: [первая](http://nikic.github.io/2015/05/05/Internal-value-representation-in-PHP-7-part-1.html), [вторая](http://nikic.github.io/2015/06/19/Internal-value-representation-in-PHP-7-part-2.html). Есть перевод на русский: [первая часть](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/257999/), [вторая](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/261131/). Затем статьи именно про объекты [PHP5](http://jpauli.github.io/2015/03/24/zoom-on-php-objects.html) ([перевод](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/255237/)), изменения устройства в [PHP7](http://jpauli.github.io/2016/01/14/php-7-objects.html) ([перевод](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/275497/))

Ответы-ссылки на so не рекомендуются, но это огромный пласт материала и даже основы в понятной форме за разумный объём текста я изложить не смогу, но и предлагать конкретизировать вопрос тоже не считаю верным в этом случае.

Comment: ухх, материала много, только сложность заключается в том что я слабо знаю C

Comment: Последнюю статью не прочитал, но что я могу сказать из всего прочитанного:
1. Очень трудно понять, практически не понятен приводимый код
2. Нет подсветки кода на хабре из-за чего читаемость падает до 0, из-за того что названия типов бывает очень длинным и с использованием нижнего подчеркивания, то же касается и названия переменных.
3. Из прочитанных мною трех статьей было выяснено, что при написания движка PHP использовался C и структуры (складывается впечатление что классов нет в С)
4. Особо конечно я не понял, но картину так сказать посмотрел...чую потом придется учить С или C++.

Comment: Как думаете "что лучше" выучить С или С++, интересует не с точки зрения холивара а с точки зрения полезности в целом.
P.S Если знать хотя бы один из языков то прочтение тех статей дадут мощное понимание, хотя структура структур...ахаха...кхм довольно запутанная. Но даже так слабо зная C я чучуть понял. Немного, но я удовлетворен на пока что =)

Comment: В C на самом деле нет классов, больше 40 лет языку. А php под капотом - далеко не эталон чистого кода. C или плюсы для полезности в целом... Не могу ничего конкретного посоветовать, лучше оба понемногу.

Comment: Я нашел одну книгу по С от Гриффитсов, думаю книга хороша, мне бы базы понимать да и вообще сишный код в целом, т.к впоследствии думаю на С/С++ писать. P.S Ранее я изучал совсем немнго С++, с С не был знаком вот почему я написал что (складывается впечатление что классов нет в С), т.к в C++ они то есть я помню. Именно тогда когда я изучал С++, у меня возникла каша между классами и структурами ибо потому что я был далек от этого, хотя и сейчас не особо близок

Comment: То есть по факту как написано в тех статьях приходим к тому что в переменной хранится handle ID объекта (промежуточные данные для извечения объекта). Только интересно какой это тип данных на языке C? Указатель? Или просто целое число которое впоследствии используется для поиска в таблице объектов? В статье просто это не написано

Answer (score 1):

Там хранится указатель на созданный объект

```php
$obj = new A; // Создали объект, разместили его в памяти и 
              // присвоили переменной $obj указатель на эту память
$cop = $obj;  // присвоили переменной $cop значение, хранящееся в $obj
              // т.к. в $obj хранился указатель на объект, то у этого
              // объекта увеличиваем счетчик ссылок на 1, чтобы объект не
              // разрушился досрочно
              // сейчас $cop и $obj хранят указатель, на один и тот же объект
$ref = &$obj; // присваиваем $ref указатель на $obj, которая хранит указатель на объект
              // в $ref хранится указатель на указатель на объект
$obj->value = 1;  // изменили поле объекта
echo $obj->value," ",$cop->value," ",$ref->value,"\n"; /// 1 1 1 
                                     // вывели три раза поле одного и того же объекта
$obj = NULL;    // присвоили $obj нулевой указатель и тем самым "отвязали" его от объекта.
                // У объекта счетчик ссылок уменьшаем на 1.
                //  Т.к. текущее значение счетчика 1 ($cop еще ссылается на объект),
                // то объект не уничтожаем
var_dump($obj, $cop, $ref); /// NULL object(A)#1 NULL
                 // $obj мы обнулили сами,
                 // $cop ссылается на живой объект,
                 // $ref ссылается на $obj и принимает то же самое значение, что и $obj
```

Comment: В целом правильно...но все равно размыто и не точно. Но в любом случае, думаю что ваш ответ полезен (проголосую)